# run a background task by url in php

Tags: php

I want to call a process once user submit the form. I am using codeigniter so the process will be called from the url(`www.example.com/index.php/update_users`). I had read the code form the thread "[php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)" for `shell_exec()` but it gives me blank output so I  am not able to debug it also. Is there any other way to do so? or any how we can run the `shell_exec`. I don't want to execute any linux command, all I need to do is call a url in background so that I can update my database silently because it's taking too much time(approx 45 sec) if running in browser.

Comment: That's not how you should do it. Following MVC pattern you should simply call the function connected with the respective route from your php code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pipe the exec's output into a log file;

```
exec('/usr/bin/myprogram > /tmp/myprogram-debug.log 2>&1');
```

You can then read it from there once it finished (or log it on the go, using tail -f (`tail -f /tmp/mypgrogram-debug.log` )